# ternary Golay code

Tags: coding-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem from the book *Introduction to coding Theory*:
[image]

I tried to solve it by myself but I think I was wrong: I tried to compute the parity check matrix and then to show that 6 columns of the parity check matrix are linearly dependent..
After that, I found a solution, but I'm having trouble understanding it..
That's the solution I found:

[image]

I cannot understand why is it useful to compute the rank of the matrix J+I and why since the rank is 4, then the dimension is 6. I had deduced te dimension directly from the definition of the parity check matrix: since G is 6x12, then the length of the code is 12 & the dimension is 6.
Moreover: what can we deduce from the generator matrix?
I can also not understand why then the minimum distance is either 3 or 6..

Thx in advance ;))

Comment: Don't you need to **prove** that $C$ is self-dual? How about showing that $G$ has rank $6$ and that $GG^t=O$?

Comment: Do you mean: we want to prove that the code is self dual (so then n'=n & k=n/2), so one can just prove that G is full rank &  = ? why is it so?